# jQuery tablesorter works for MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm but not dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I have a problem with sorting columns containing a date and time with jQuery tablesorter.

Basically what is printed by a JSP page on the table is following the formatDate pattern `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm`

An example of what is printed on the page would be `<td>07/06/2018 03:27</td>`

I tried by setting the header of the column like this:

```
$('.c-rule__preview').tablesorter({
  headers: { 0: { sorter: false } , 9: { sorter: 'shortDate', dateFormat: 'ddmmyyyy' } }
});
```

but it doesn't work. It does some sort of sorting but it's wrong.

The interesting thing is that if I switch to american format (`MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm` as formatDate pattern and `{ sorter: 'shortDate', dateFormat: 'mmddyyyy' }` in the JS it works flawlessy.

I also tried with `dateFormat: 'uk'` just in case even though my version of the plugin is 2.0.5b and it doesn't work either.

[This table](https://codepen.io/a_effe/pen/mKBMqM) demonstrates the problem I am referring to.

Comment: Can you share your code ? I tried with example, It seems to be working fine . https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eKGWrv

Comment: The JSP part writing data to the table is https://pastebin.com/Z8SpsmB7 while on my app init's I have https://pastebin.com/0Rf38GxK when i try to sort ascending i get https://i.imgur.com/1tCljOV.png which is wrong, same dates on american format works well though

Comment: This are the elements I'm trying to sort (innerHTML of each td as seen by jQuery) https://i.imgur.com/7zcX50K.png

Comment: share your html source file for that table. That would be easier to reproduce than a image

Comment: That's my table if you wanna play with it https://codepen.io/a_effe/pen/GGMEjg as you can see the problem is the same, when sort ascending the 3th onward are correctly in order, but the first two are not! same thing when sorting descending, all correct but the last two (different month)

Comment: The problem can also be reproduced on your table by switching dates to other months/years https://codepen.io/a_effe/pen/mKBMqM

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, tablesorter didn't consider the `dateFormat` parameter passed in the `headers` object.

I solved my issue by editing the library JS file, changing `dateFormat: "us"` with `dateFormat: "uk"` in `this.defaults`